# Linear Algebra - Inner Products, Functions, and Closet Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials, inner-products, span

This is the question:

> Formulate the linear algebra problem of finding the closet poly $p \in span \{1, t^2\}$ to the function $f(t)=e^tcos(t)$ with respect to the L$^2$ inner product: $\lt f,g\gt = \int^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx$ (do not solve!)

My question is:

1. What is L$^2$?
2. How do you take the inner product of two functions?
3. Are they asking for an orthagonal polynomial to f(t)?
4. Lastly, how do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. In this case $L^2=\{f : \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx<1\}$.
2. By definition $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{o}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$.
3. No, they're asking for such a polynomial $p(x)=a+bx^2$ that $\|f-p\|^2=\langle f-p,f-p\rangle$ is smallest possible.
4. Find projection $f$ onto subspace $\text{span}\{1,t^2\}$, for example [here](https://www.math.ku.edu/open/LinearAlgebraNotes-Lerner/Chapter20.pdf) you can find an algorithm.